# How fix NumberFormatException in round double

Tags: kotlin, double, precision

Im' trying to round a double but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,2119"
```

This is my code

```
0.2119.roundTo(precision)
fun Double.roundTo(numFractionDigits: Int): Double {
    return "%.${numFractionDigits}f".format(this, Locale.ENGLISH).toDouble()
}
```

How can round a double correctly

Comment: It seems to work in the Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/0Yha_oygD

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
fun Double.roundTo(numFractionDigits: Int): Double {
 return  "%.${numFractionDigits}f".format(this).toDouble()
}

val i=9.8593525
i.roundTo(3) // 9.859
```